# Opening parents of a nested navigator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code for a navigator which I that works like an accordion.

A picture to demonstrate my navigator:

[image]

Ignore the "wierd characters", this is my language.

this is a code example of how it build:
http://jsfiddle.net/uXA7E/3/

As you can see, the navigator is max 3 levels depth.

What I'm trying to achieve is that if the user is browsing category with the id of "13" or so with jQuery I will pick the element with the **class** of 13, and then reveal all the way down to it and mark it in some color.

this is how a link build:

```
<a class="13" href="category.php?cid=13">בלוקים ודפדפות</a>
```

I do have an element on the page that holds the ID that im viewing:

```
<input type="hidden" value="13" id="cid">
```

This is the code that I tried:

```
var until = document.getElementsByClassName('depth-two');
$("."+$("#cid").val()).prevUntil(until,"ul").show();
```

AND:

```
$("."+$("#cid").val()).prevAll("ul").show();
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work at all.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh, I thought it might be Galactic Basic.

Comment: Please, leave this. This isn't the issue of this topic. Please try to focus on my problem and suggest solutions.

Comment: Can you more clearly describe what does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you almost had it. Try this instead:

```
$("."+$("#cid").val()).parents("ul").show();
```

`jQuery.prevAll` matches all siblings, but you want to match parents.

#### Sibling

A sibling is `next` to another element. For example:

```
<div>
    <p>Sibling 1</p>
    <p>Sibling 2</p>
</div>
```

Sibling1 and Sibling 2 are siblings of each other. They share the same parent. They are both children of the same parent.

You wanted to search for parents, though.

#### Parent

```
<ul id="A">
    <li id="AA">
        <ul id="AAA">
            <li id="AAAA"></li>
            <li id="AAAB"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="AB">
        <ul id="ABA">
            <li id="ABAA"></li>
            <li id="ABAB"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Referring to the above example, There is a single, top-level parent element with `id="A"`. We will refer to elements by their `id`.

- Element `AA` has sibling `AB`, and parent `A`.
- Element `AB` has sibling `AA`, and parent `A`.
- Element `AAA` has parent `AA`, and grandparent `A`.
- Element `ABA` has parent `AB`, and grandparent `A`.
- Element `ABAA` has sibling `ABAB`, parent `ABA`, grandparent `AB`, and great-grandparent `A`.
- Element `ABAB` has sibling `ABAA`, parent `ABA`, grandparent `AB`, and great-grandparent `A`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this one works, I just don't understand why the `prevAll` didn't work as i expected

Comment: Let me know if this makes more sense, or if I should revise.

Comment: yes, it's very usefull. 
One more question if i may, I wanna color the `li` parent of the selected `<a>` tag with some color, I tried `$("."+$("#cid").val()).prev('li')` in order to select that `li` but it didn't work, any idea why?

Comment: Because the `li` is a parent, not a sibling. `prev` is a sibling selector. Use `.parent('li')` instead.

Comment: I tried .parent('li'), it didnt work, but if i used .parent.parent, it did work. :/

Comment: @kfirba, then that means that your `a` tag has another parent before the `li` tag.

Comment: that's correct, it has a `div` parent first.
But is there really no other efficient way to do it? and, if the `parent` method works only when the element is a an immidiate child of the element, why would I specify the type I want? .parent and .parent('li') would result the same way, there can't be 2 parents to an element so it seems useless :o
`<li>   <div>  <a>asd</a>  </div>   </li>` if I did `$('a').parent()` I would get the `<div>` and if i did `$('a').parent('li')` i would be returned with nothing. so in-order to get the li, i will have to do `$('a').parent().parent()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37210/discussion-between-kfirba-and-crush)

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of `prevUntil` or `prevAll` (which selects siblings) you are looking for the [`parents` method](http://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
$(liselector).parents('ul').slideDown().prev('.do').text('-');
```

(see [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uXA7E/4/))